# jQuery etc. Instantiation

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

OOP usually requires instantiation (creating an instance of class before using) like this:

```
var x = new String();
```

In jQuery (and other frameworks) we can use object without instantiation, e.g.(no 'new'):

```
$('#myid').click(function(){
//code
});
```

Here's my question: how do framework authors make it?? How to make framework ready for use without 'new' instantiation??

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I can't tell if you're asking about the `'#myid'` string, or the jQuery object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

javascript is a [prototype based language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming), there is no inheritance - all behavior is achieved by cloning objects and/or attaching new fields to existing objects.

In the example you have given

```
$('#myid').click(function(){
//code
});
```

you are actually passing an anonymous function to the `click` function which is defined as an inner function on an object defined by the jQuery library - which is created via the global parametrized `$` function (which internally uses `new` as pointed out by @lwburk in his answer). Functions are first class citizens in javascript - they can be used directly, or as part of an object, which then makes them appear as if they were methods within the outer object:

```
 [object returned by function]
 $            ('#myid')       .click(          function() {} );
 ^             ^               ^
 function      parameters      inner function  ^ parameter of type function
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say *"by cloning objects (the prototypes)"*? If you're saying that a duplicate prototype object is created for each instance, that's not correct.

Comment: @patrick looks like I needed a refresher on javascript prototypes as well, your previous [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841175/trying-to-understand-the-point-of-prototypes-in-javascript/4841209#4841209) was quite helpful

Answer (score 5):

The simplest, hand-waviest answer (that leaves out a lot about how JavaScript is different from class-based languages) is that a new object *is* created and returned from the jQuery function.

One of the first things you'll see in the jQuery source:

```
var jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
}
```

You can see that `$` is simply an alias for `jQuery` later in the source:

```
// Expose jQuery to the global object
return (window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make a method that is wrapped with a self-evoking function.

```
(function() {
    var iAm = window.iAm || {};

    iAm = {
        Awesome: function()
        {
            alert('Yea you are!');
        },

        Lame: function()
        {
            alert('aww man.');
        }
    };

    window.iAm = iAm;

})();

iAm.Awesome(); // will alert "Yea you are!"
iAm.Lame(); // will alert "aww man."
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a dynamic, scripting, prototype-based language. The instantiation and memory management comes from the interpreter.

Comment: but what about 'new'?? usually instances are created with 'new'!

Comment: You don't need it in most circumstances.

Comment: @DrStrangeLove - Daniel's right that you don't need `new` in JavaScript, strictly speaking, but jQuery does in fact use `new` to create a new object that's assigned to the `jQuery` and `$` objects. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because JS is prototypal, functional and class-less, the `new` keyword is a bit different from other languages.

The difference between

```
var D = new Dog();
```

and

```
var D = Dog();
```

is that using the `new` keyword will return the object for which it is invoking.

Consider this:

```
function Dog() {

  // a property
  this.breed = "chocolate lab";

  // a method
  this.bark = function(){
    alert("woof");
  }
}
```

Then you can call methods and pull properties from the object.

```
var D = new Dog();

    D.breed; // [string] 'chocolate lab'
    D.bark(); // alerts "woof"
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Crockford school, to embrace the true prototypical nature of JavaScript you have to abolish pseudo-classical elements such as the `new` operator or the `.prototype` reference.

While lwburk is right in that in jQuery, `$()` is just a wrapper, you can actually 'instantiate' an object without `new`.

```
var myClass = function () {
  var privateVar,

  instance = {
    member: 'foo',
    method: function () {
      privateVar = 'bar';
    }
  };

  return instance;
};

var newInstance = myClass();
```

Comment: What you write here is wrong in many ways. First, to work as you expect it, myClass should be a function and not a literal object. Even if you correct this, you will inadvertently create a global variable instance. Finally the point is not whether to use `new` or not: this is just a different way of invoking a function (that is, `new foo()` is usually not equivalent to `foo()`. You should **not** abolish `new` and keep using constructors. What you can to is to mostly avoid constructors and only use them for inheritance. This comment is too short to expand on this point.

Comment: Sorry, I did forget the function header. Please point me to some resources that do expand on this. I'm curious.